# C# converting decimal to string by seperating digits

Tags: c#, replace, decimal, digit

```
decimal value = 10000;
var str = value.ToString("N0").Replace(",",".");
Output : 10.000
```

Is there a better way to seperate digits without using `Replace` ?

Comment: See the marked answer in the duplicate. Use the `customCulture` in that answer as the `IFormatProvider` in `ToString` as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

```
decimal value = 10000;
var str = value.ToString("N0",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Also, you can configure the culture as you wish. Like;

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-En")
```

Please refer this post;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, it's worked.